# Varnish ignores settings in /etc/default/varnish

Tags: ubuntu, varnish

Varnish 4.1.1 completely ignores settings in the /etc/default/varnish file on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I'm looking for a solution.

Result of `/bin/systemctl status varnish.service`

```
Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomple
lines 1-14/14 (END)
● varnish.service - Varnish HTTP accelerator
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-01-09 01:24:09 UTC; 15h ago
     Docs: https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.1/
           man:varnishd
 Main PID: 9470 (varnishd)
    Tasks: 218
   Memory: 67.5M
      CPU: 45.584s
   CGroup: /system.slice/varnish.service
           ├─9470 /usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :6081 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret
           └─9483 /usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :6081 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

Comment: Could you post the output of `/bin/systemctl status  varnish.service` and the content of `/usr/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `Varnish` will try to load the `default.vcl` which is located at this path `/etc/varnish/default.vcl` as you see in here:

```
CGroup: /system.slice/varnish.service
           ├─9470 /usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :6081 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret
           └─9483 /usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :6081 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret
```

if you would like to load another file which will be located at another path then you need to open this file `/etc/varnish/varnish.params` and modify the value of this line:

```
# Main configuration file. You probably want to change it.                       
VARNISH_VCL_CONF=/etc/varnish/default.vcl
```

This works with Varnish 4+

Comment: I have the same probelm with varnish 5, there is no file "varnish.params" in the /etc/varnish folder. I modify the default.vcl file but my varnish doesn't start

Comment: According to the latest version of Varnish on CentOS , the rpm contains `/etc/varnish/varnish.params` so it should be exist. and sure it will be the same for ubuntu , what is the output of this command: `varnishd ~d ~f /etc/varnish/default.vcl` ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the output is : Error:
Message from VCC-compiler:
VCL version declaration missing\nUpdate your VCL to Version 4 syntax, and add\n vcl 4.0;\non the first line the VCL files.\n('/etc/varnish/default.vcl' Line 12 Pos 1)\nbackend default {\n#######----------\nRunning VCC-compiler failed, exited with 2\nVCL compilation failed

But I find my mistake, the project is on Varnish 3.0.5 and I have Varnish 4.1.1

Answer (score 3):

This is, apparently, intentional behaviour in upstream Debian:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=749272

/etc/default/varnish is used by /etc/init.d/varnish exclusively on purpose.

"If you want to use /etc/default/varnish on your own, you can override
/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service in /etc/systemd/system/varnish.service, but I'll recommend you just write the wanted commandline options in
/etc/systemd/system/varnish.service, instead of reading /etc/default/varnish "

varnish.service is in .INI format. This tutorial gives an example for Debian: http://deshack.net/how-to-varnish-listen-port-80-systemd/

Varnish have added in the official docs:

https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/tutorial/putting_varnish_on_port_80.html#debian-v8-ubuntu-v15-04

e.g. the varnish.service on the Varnish I've just set up on 16.04 has this line (the box is called cache1):

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -s file,/var/lib/varnish/cache1/varnish_storage.bin,85G -n cache1
```

Once you've changed this *do not forget to reload systemd:*

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

*Then* restart Varnish. Check your results with /bin/systemctl status varnish.service .

**tl;dr** you need to put your config in *both* places.

Answer (score 3):

On ubuntu 19.04 :

sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/varnish.service (change the port)

sudo systemctl daemon-reload && sudo systemctl restart varnish && sudo systemctl status varnish

curl localhost